# TabBar is hiding after updating viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uikit, viewcontroller, tabbar

In my code, when tapping to a button viewcontroller should update. I use this code for updating ViewController.

```swift
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PersonalViewController") as! PersonalViewController

let appDlg = self.view.window!.windowScene!.delegate as? SceneDelegate
appDlg?.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

But, after updating viewController, TabBar, that is situated in the bottom, dissapears. I don't know how to solve that problem. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```swift
appDlg?.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

you are overriding your entire view hierarchy and make the `PersonalViewController` your apps root and the `UITabBarController` deallocates, hence the no longer present tab bar.

Instantiating a new ViewController from scratch is not a way to refresh/update your view state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so, how can I update my view in other way?